# What do non-invariant and non-orthogonal eigenvectors of an orthogonal matrix look like?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose two vectors $u, v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ are non-invariant non-orthogonal eigenvectors of an orthogonal $n \times n$ matrix $A$. What are the eigenvalues of $A$ associated to the eigenvectors $u$ and $v$?

Let $w$ be a non-zero vector such that $Aw = \lambda w$. Then $\lambda \overline{\lambda} \langle w, w \rangle = \langle \lambda w, \lambda w \rangle = \langle Aw, Aw \rangle = \langle w, A^{T}Aw \rangle = \langle w, w \rangle$.
Since $\langle, \rangle $ is non-degenerate by definition, $\langle w, w \rangle \neq 0$ so that every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ must satisfy: $\lambda \overline{\lambda} = 1$.

Now, suppose $Av = \lambda_{v}v$ and $Au = \lambda_{u} u$.
Then $\lambda_{v}\overline{\lambda_{u}}\langle v, u \rangle = \langle \lambda_{v}v, \lambda_{u}u \rangle = \langle Av, Au \rangle = \langle v, u \rangle$. (*)

Since, $v$ and $u$ are non-orthogonal, it follows from (*) that $\lambda_{v}\overline{\lambda_{u}} =1$. So that $\lambda_{u} = \lambda_{v}\overline{\lambda_{u}}\lambda_{u} = \lambda_{v}$.

Since, $u$ and $v$ are real, $\lambda = \overline{\lambda}$. So that $\lambda = \pm 1$.

I want to rule out $\lambda = -1$. But I guess my difficulty is that I honestly do not know what is meant by non-invariant, which is a concept I haven't invoked and I suspect it is the key to showing that such eigenvalues are identically 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that "non-invariant" means $Au\ne u$, $Av\ne v$. So it is $\lambda=1$ that you rule out.

Comment: Thank you. I once didn't know how to solve a problem because I didn't know what a die was that the problem was asking to roll a certain number of times:-).